# If $a+b+c+d=3$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=45$ then find the value of $\dots$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b+c+d=3$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=45$ then find the value of:

$\frac{a^5}{(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)}+\frac{b^5}{(b-a)(b-c)(b-d)}+\frac{c^5}{(c-a)(c-b)(c-d)}+\frac{d^5}{(d-a)(d-b)(d-c)}$

**Hint written in the book**:Because the polynomial is symmetric use that for simplifying the polynomial the use the knowledge of question to find the value of the polynomial.

Now my problem is that how should we use the symmetric of polynomial for simplifying it.Could you help me?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to add more assumptions such as $a\ne b\ne c\ne d$?

Comment: @polfosol no I just have to say they are real.

Comment: Let $a=c$ and $b=d$, then you would get $$a= \frac{3}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{19}\right),b= \frac{3}{4} \left(\sqrt{19}+1\right)$$ while the expression is undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will show that the expression is equal to $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 + ab + ac+ ad + bc + bd + cd$$
Taking the common denominator as $(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(b-c)(b-d)(c-d)$, the numerator of the given expression can be written as
$$a^5(b-c)(b-d)(c-d) - b^5(a-c)(a-d)(c-d)+c^5(a-b)(a-d)(b-d) - d^5(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$$
Clearly, this expression vanishes for $a=b, a=c, a=d, b=c, b=d, c=d$. Thus the given expression is a polynomial expression of degree 2 and symmetric in $a,b,c,d$. Thus we can write it as 
$$\alpha(a+b+c+d) + \beta(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) + \gamma(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$$
Thus we can write
\begin{align*}
&a^5(b-c)(b-d)(c-d) - b^5(a-c)(a-d)(c-d)+c^5(a-b)(a-d)(b-d) - d^5(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)=\\
&(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(b-c)(b-d)(c-d)(\alpha(a+b+c+d) + \beta(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) + \gamma(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd))
\end{align*}
Comparing coefficient of $a^5$, we get $\beta = 1$ and comparing coefficient of $a^4$, we can see that $\alpha = 0$ and $\gamma = 1$. Also, 
$$ ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd = \frac{1}{2}((a+b+c+d)^2 - (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)) = -18$$
Thus the required answer is 27.

Comment: It seems to me you have found the value of the  common numerator of the expression.

Comment: @user254665 No. We have shown the given expression is equal to $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd$

Comment: I mis-read your second-last line. +1.

Answer (score 2):

I offer an alternative interpretation of Muralidharan's answer.

Taken to the common denominator, you will get terms such as

$$a^5(b-c)(c-d)(d-b)+\text{cyclic permutations}$$
where you noticed I ordered the terms into cyclic form (b→c→d→b→c→d→...)

This form now looks like a column expansion of a 4×4 matrix. The expressed term would be $a^5$ times the 3×3 minor. Which one? If you are familiar with Vandermonde matrices, you may recognize
$$(b-c)(c-d)(d-b)=\det\begin{bmatrix}1& b & b^2\\1&c &c^2\\1&d&d^2\end{bmatrix}$$

The whole numerator is thus

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}1& a & a^2 & a^5\\1& b & b^2 & b^5\\1&c &c^2&c^5\\1&d&d^2&d^5\end{bmatrix}$$
On the other hand, the denominator is a product of differences of all pairs of 4 numbers, which is a determinant of a vandermonde matrix of order $4$. The whole expression is therefore equal to

$$\frac{\det\begin{bmatrix}1& a & a^2 & a^5\\1& b & b^2 & b^5\\1&c &c^2&c^5\\1&d&d^2&d^5\end{bmatrix}}{\det\begin{bmatrix}1& a & a^2 & a^3\\1& b & b^2 & b^3\\1&c &c^2&c^3\\1&d&d^2&d^3\end{bmatrix}}$$
which is recognizable as Cramer's rule for the 4th component of the solution of
$$\begin{bmatrix}1& a & a^2 & a^3\\1& b & b^2 & b^3\\1&c &c^2&c^3\\1&d&d^2&d^3\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}a^5\\b^5\\c^5\\d^5\end{bmatrix}$$
which can be interpreted as looking for an interpolating polynomial of order $3$ in 4 points (a,b,c,d), to match the polynomial $x^5$ in the same points. We want the leading coefficient.

Multiply with the transpose of the same matrix and you can express everything with power sums $s_n=a^n+b^n+c^n+d^n$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}s_0& s_1 & s_2 & s_3\\s_1& s_2 & s_3 & s_4\\s_2&s_3&s_4&s_5\\s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}s_5 \\s_6\\s_7\\s_8\end{bmatrix}$$

I was hoping to get somewhere with that, given that we know $s_0$, $s_1$ and $s_2$ but I got lost in the Newton's identities. I'm leaving this here as inspiration, if anyone can give it a nice finish.

Comment: Nice try $\qquad$